# Sort sqlite database by time on android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sorting

I am using this code-

```
myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName+ " ORDER BY "+ params[0], null);
```

to sort a table by columns and it works great except one of the columns is time (like in itunes) i.e. 2:35 for 2 minutes 35 seconds. This causes it to sort incorrectly. How can I sort it the proper way? I am using sqlite for android.

Comment: You table structure? sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the date as 2:35, you can have the column store seconds, and would thus be 155 (2 minutes, 35 seconds = 155 seconds).  Thus it would sort it fine.  You could translate seconds to minutes/seconds in the code.

Or, if you wanted to, you could have two columns, minutes and seconds.

It does not make sense to store time in a format like 2:35 if you are manipulating the data.

Comment: Ah why didn't I think of that? I will store it in seconds thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store Time since epoch that is milliseconds since 01/01/1970 and you can then sort it however you like. Saving time like this lets you forget about worries of many issues that require effort.

Here it is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731218/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-from-epoch-1970-01-01-in-java).