# How do I get milliseconds from epoch (1970-01-01) in Java?

Tags: java, date

I need to get the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01 UTC until now UTC in Java.

I would also like to be able to get the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01 UTC to any other UTC date time.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: it does not show any research effort.

Comment: @PaulG - Number one reason for downvote is *research effort*. The question is solved by a simple google.

Comment: This [link may be of help](http://bit.ly/TImRxd).

Answer (score 209, accepted):

How about [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)?

From the JavaDoc:

**Returns:** *the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC*

**Java 8** introduces the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework, particularly the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class which "*...models a ... point on the time-line...*":

```
long now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
```

**Returns:** *the number of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z* -- i.e. pretty much the same as above :-)

Comment: As this answer was 2012 and Java 8 was not around it is a good one.  Equally good is the java.time answer from Prezemek.  That considers the current Java 8 java.time framework.

Comment: For Edification:  I tested a couple of ways to get a UTC time in Milliseconds and found java.time.Instant.now().toEpochMilli  to work well.  I compared this to ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) method options (which I have seen in other posts as options) and as expected, the Java.time.Instant.now() approach was a little faster on my machine ... low single digit milliseconds on thirty consecutive runs.

Comment: Remember also that `System.currentTimeInMs()` does not update every millisecond!

Answer (score 61):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
import java.time.Instant;

Instant.now().toEpochMilli(); //Long = 1450879900184
Instant.now().getEpochSecond(); //Long = 1450879900
```

This works in UTC because `Instant.now()` is really call to `Clock.systemUTC().instant()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html

Answer (score 17):

Also try `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Answer (score -2):

You can also try

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

getTimeInMillis() - the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch

Comment: This terrible date-time class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310. See modern solution in Answers by Bystrup & Hack-R

Comment: Modern solution using `java.time.Instant` seen in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731260/642706) and [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34437574/642706)